# Magento - Get Transactional Email Variables

Tags: magento, transactional-email

I was just reading over

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index#email_variables
```

Anyone know how I can find these variables on my own? The wiki page says they may not actually work, and the variable I am trying to work with is {{var shippingMethod}}, however, it is returning blank.

I am wondering, one if that is the correct variable name, and two, if that is the correct variable name, what function do I need to add to my custom shipping method?

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the piece of code that migiht help You:

```
public function sendMail() {
    $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
    $template = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE); // template id of email template
    $email = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT); // recipient example: example@yahoo.com
    $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area'=>'frontend'))
        ->sendTransactional(
        $template,
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
        $email,
        null,
        array(
            'subject'   => $this->getSubject(),
            'line'      => $this->getLine(),
            'message'   => $this->getMessage()
        )
    );
    $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
    return $this;
}
```

the array of

```
        array(
            'subject'   => $this->getSubject(),
            'line'      => $this->getLine(),
            'message'   => $this->getMessage()
        )
```

can be get by {{var subject}} {{var line}} {{var message}}

---

Then how to get shippingMethod ??

You must **getModel of shipping method** and **load the shipping method** first and then **set it to the array**.